# Dynamic GridView for android application

Tags: android, gridview

I want to generate a dynamic grid view with a minimum of 2 buttons and a maximum of 16 buttons. The buttons are images and I want the images to adjust their sizes depending upon the number of buttons in the grid view. I am not using any library because I tried to use different libraries but they didn't work. I have implemented my own logic to generate a dynamic grid view with variable buttons sizes. The problem that I face is that its not looking professional as the images stretch and look weird. Here is a screen shot of my dynamic grid view activity. I want the images of buttons to auto adjust according to the size of the button i.e. not be stretched.

[image]

Here is my code

Gridview.java

```
public void CreateGrid(int NoOfRooms, String names[]) {
    int RoomsOnTheRight = NoOfRooms / 2;
    int RoomsOnTheLeft = NoOfRooms - RoomsOnTheRight;
    Button[] Rooms = new Button[NoOfRooms];
    // create buttons and set their layout parameters
    for (int i = 0; i < NoOfRooms; i++) {
        float size = getSizeOfRoom(names[i]);
        Rooms[i] = new Button(this);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lay = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, size);
        lay.leftMargin = 4;
        lay.rightMargin = 4;
        lay.bottomMargin = 4;
        lay.topMargin = 4;
        Rooms[i].setLayoutParams(lay);
    }
    // Insert buttons on the right column of the GridView
    for (int i = 0; i < RoomsOnTheRight; i++) {
        LeftColumn.addView(Rooms[i]);
        Rooms[i].setText(NamesOfRooms[i]);
        Rooms[i].setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        Rooms[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        AcquireImage(NamesOfRooms[i], Rooms[i]);
        Rooms[i].setTag("room" + (i + 1) + ".txt");
        Rooms[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                OscarVoice.setSpeechRate(0.8f);
                OscarVoice.speak("Hello", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                Intent roomintent = new Intent("com.log.oscar.ROOMVIEW");
                roomintent.putExtra("filename", v.getTag().toString());
                startActivity(roomintent);
            }
        });

    }
    // Insert buttons on the left column of the GridView
    for (int i = 0; i < RoomsOnTheLeft; i++) {
        RightColumn.addView(Rooms[i + RoomsOnTheRight]);
        Rooms[i + RoomsOnTheRight]
                .setText(NamesOfRooms[i + RoomsOnTheRight]);
        Rooms[i + RoomsOnTheRight].setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        Rooms[i + RoomsOnTheRight]
                .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        AcquireImage(NamesOfRooms[i + RoomsOnTheRight], Rooms[i
                + RoomsOnTheRight]);
        Rooms[i + RoomsOnTheRight].setTag("room"
                + (i + RoomsOnTheRight + 1) + ".txt");
        Rooms[i + RoomsOnTheRight]
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent roomintent = new Intent(
                                "com.log.oscar.ROOMVIEW");
                        roomintent.putExtra("filename", v.getTag()
                                .toString());
                        startActivity(roomintent);
                    }
                });

    }

}
```

Gridview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/speechview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bspeech"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try StaggeredGridView to get your result

Comment: try this demo for creating Gridview : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/705639/how-to-create-gridview-in-android-programaticall

Comment: u can use 2 linear layout for 2 column

Comment: @Saif I tried this but this is not what I want. I want the images to adjust according to the space means if there are only two images they display in two columns and screen doesn't look weird. I don't want to fix their positions but adjust according to number of images.

Comment: @Darshan I have done the same in my code.

Comment: see this demo some help you : 
1)https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid
2)https://github.com/jpardogo/ListBuddies
3)https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView

Comment: @Saif I tried StaggeredGridView, it looks much better. Thanks.